# Anyone seen a list of tricky Haskell exercises?

Tags: haskell, monads

Are there any lists of tricky Haskell exercises that use monads in surprising ways floating around?  I'm most interested in simple 'work out what this line of code does' or 'do this in point free using this monad' type questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Blow_your_mind

Answer (score 7):

Try to figure out why the programs [here](http://math.andrej.com/2007/09/28/seemingly-impossible-functional-programs/) terminate.

Answer (score 7):

It's not about monads, but these [20 intermediate haskell exercises](http://blog.tmorris.net/20-intermediate-haskell-exercises/) could make your evening.

Comment: What is it about if not about monads?

Comment: It's now : https://tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/20-intermediate-haskell-exercises/

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you call tricky, but if you've never tied the knot you should try to make iterative depth first search using knot tying (and make sure it terminates cleanly if no solution is found!).

Comment: If you're not aware: [Tying the Knot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot)